# Namespace and Type issue

Tags: c#, namespaces

I have a solution with two projects. One namespace is `MarketplaceWebServiceOrders` and the other is `MarketsplaceWebServiceOrders.Sample`. I have public interface in the `MarketplaceWebServiceOrders` called `MarketplaceWebServiceOrders`. My main function is in `MarketplaceWebServiceOrders.Sample` and whenever I try to use the interface `MarketplaceWebServiceOrders` I get `Error: MarketplaceWebServiceOrders.Samples.MarketplaceWebServiceOrders is namespace used use like a type`.

I actually have this program compiled and running but I need to make changes and this popped up.

Comment: See: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/namespaces/ Start reading near the bottom.

Comment: Do try to come up with better names.  An interface type name should always begin with the letter I.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram I using a third party library that I really can't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can access your interface specifying full name with namespace:

```
MarketplaceWebServiceOrders.MarketplaceWebServiceOrders instance = new ...();
```

Anyway, your naming looks wrong. You are probably misusing namespaces - they should "categorize" types, no need to have type name the same as namespace. Moreover, interfaces are prefixed with `I` letter by good convention.

Comment: How do I do that for a parameter in a method call?

Comment: Exactly the same: `void MyMethod(MarketplaceWebServiceOrders.MarketplaceWebServiceOrders parameter)`. A bit messy, isn't it?

Comment: When I try that it ask if I want to generate a stub and I the stub I generate is MarketplaMarketplaceWebServiceOrders.Samples.MarketplaceWebServiceOrders namespace.

Comment: Are you referencing your original `MarketplaceWebServiceOrders` project correctly? Are you sure you don't have any web service proxy code generated within your `Sample` project?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider refactoring your code to make the namespace and types a little less ambiguous. One of the purposes of namespaces is to organize code, so it's a bit redundant to have the same name in both the namespace and the type.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error states that you have an additional namespace level MarketplaceWebServiceOrders in the MarketplaceWebServiceOrders.Sample namespace. Is this true? If so, you will need to fully qualify the usage of the interface from the base namespace: `MarketplaceWebServiceOrders.MarketplaceWebServiceOrders` is the interface you say you want. Just don't use the base MarketplaceWebServiceOrders namespace in this code file.

To avoid this confusion if at all possible I would change the namespace name or the interface. The interface would be easier; add an "I" to the front of the identifier if it is an actual C# interface type (it's recommended naming convention in most C-style languages).